# AWS Boto3 BASE64 encoding error thrown when invoking client.request_spot_instances method

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, base64, boto3

I am trying to submit a request for an EC2 SPOT instance using boto3 (Environment Python 3.5,Windows 7). 
I need to pass the **UserData** parameter for running initial scripts.

The error I get is 
  File "C:\Users...\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 222, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when
calling the 
***RequestSpotInstances operation: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data Code***

I am following this documentation 
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_instances

**If I take the UserData parameter out – everything works well.**

I have tried different ways to pass the parameter but I end up with the same.similar errors.

**Boto 3 Script**

```
    client = session.client('ec2')

    myparam = str(base64.b64encode(bytes('yum install -y php', 'utf-8')))

    response = client.request_spot_instances(
    SpotPrice='0.4',
    InstanceCount=1,
    Type='one-time',
    LaunchSpecification={
    'ImageId': 'ami-xxxxxx',
    'KeyName': 'xxxxx',
    'InstanceType': 't1.micro',
    'UserData': myparam,
    'Monitoring': {
    'Enabled': True
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you shouldn't convert your base64 string to `str`. Are you using Python 3?

Replace:

```
myparam = str(base64.b64encode(bytes('yum install -y php', 'utf-8')))
```

By:

```
myparam = base64.b64encode(b'yum install -y php').decode("ascii")
```

Comment: It gives me an error Invalid type for parameter LaunchSpecification.UserData, value: b'fdfd', type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'> - Because it expects a string

Comment: The doc in not clear about the type. It says "String". Try: `base64.b64encode(b'yum install -y php').decode("ascii")`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks - I edited it to make the code more readable like this base64.b64encode('yum install -y php'.encode()).decode("ascii").